# Ignoring Special Characters in an Island Grammar

Tags: parsing, antlr4

I've the following island grammar that works fine (and I think as expected):

```
lexer grammar FastTestLexer;

// Default mode rules (the SEA)
OPEN1 : '#' -> mode(ISLAND) ; // switch to ISLAND mode
OPEN2 : '##' -> mode(ISLAND);
OPEN3 : '###' -> mode(ISLAND);
OPEN4 : '####' -> mode(ISLAND);
LISTING_OPEN : '~~~~~' -> mode(LISTING);
NL : [\r\n]+;
TEXT : ~('#'|'~')+;  // ~('#'|'~')+ ; // clump all text together

mode ISLAND;
CLOSE1 : '#' -> mode(DEFAULT_MODE) ; // back to SEA mode
CLOSE2 : '##' -> mode(DEFAULT_MODE) ; // back to SEA mode
CLOSE3 : '###' -> mode(DEFAULT_MODE) ; // back to SEA mode
CLOSE4 : '####' -> mode(DEFAULT_MODE) ; // back to SEA mode
INLINE : ~'#'+ ; // clump all text together

mode LISTING;
LISTING_CLOSE : '~~~~~' -> mode(DEFAULT_MODE);
INLINE_LISTING : ~'~'+; //~('~'|'#')+;
```

And the parser grammar:

```
parser grammar FastTextParser;

options { tokenVocab=FastTestLexer; } // use tokens from ModeTagsLexer.g4

dnpMD
    : subheadline NL headline NL lead (subheading | listing | text | NL)*
    ;

headline
    : OPEN1 INLINE CLOSE1
    ;

subheadline
    : OPEN2 INLINE CLOSE2
    ;

lead
    : OPEN3 INLINE CLOSE3
    ;

subheading
    : OPEN4 INLINE CLOSE4
    ;

listing
    : LISTING_OPEN INLINE_LISTING LISTING_CLOSE
    ;

text
    : TEXT
    ;
```

Input text like this ones working fine:

```
## Heading2 ##

# Heading1 #

### Heading3 ###

fffff

#### Heading4 ####

I'm a line.

~~~~~
ffffff
~~~~~

I'm a line, too.

#### Heading4a ####
```

The TEXT lexer token is matching all the text. Of course except '#' and '~' so the parser knows when there are headings and listings are coming.

My problem is that within the text both characters '#' and '~' should be allowed. The single '#' is only needed for the heading and this parser rule is not active within the body (just one heading at the beginning of the document).

Is there a way to allow '#' and '~' within the text without escaping? My first thought was to disallow '##' within the text:

```
TEXT : ~('##'|'~')+;
```

But multiple characters are not allowed there. :(

Maybe someone can give me a hint. But I think this isn't solvable at all. Not solvable with ANTLR4 I mean. Maybe there's another technology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to do more work in the parser and less in the lexer. Allow `#` and `~` inside `text` and not inside `TEXT`, something *similar* to:

```
text
    : TEXT
    : OPEN1
    : TEXT text
    : OPEN1 text
    ;
```

Adjust the rules for the headlines etc. accordingly.

That way, not the lexer has to decide what a `#` (or `~`) means, what can be relatively hard, because the lexer does not really know the context, but it only decides that it has seen a hash sign. Instead, the parser decides on the meaning of it, and it knows the context in which it appears.

Comment: Hm okay. Not quite sure if I understand your suggestion correctly but I'll give it a try.

Comment: Thanks. That helped me in combination with another answer on another question. ;)